# Hyperledger Fabric: How to edit membership services (fabric-membersrvc) users and passwords

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a test app finished and working under Hyperledger Fabric. It runs on secure mode and uses admin/Xurw3yU9zI0l credentials... those seem to be default and hardcoded somewhere. Everything working ok. I use fabric-peer and fabric-membersrvc dockers (v.0.6).

Where is that admin username and password stored (so I can change them and add new users before opening the Fabric ports to the world)? I can't find it as parameter in any of the docker-compose file and base subfiles used to bring up the network structure. Any docs explaining this and how does the membersrv (roles, permissions) work? Thanks for any directions.

Edited:

Let me add this here as a reference. This is the content of the example membersrvc.yaml file in v0.6 docker available at the moment. While not really a full documentation, it allows understanding the concepts. If I understand correctly, this data is copied into the user registry which then can be edited (adding users, ...) according to the rules explained in the comments. Any more info on this will surely help a lot! :-) :

```
# Default users to be registered with the CA on first launch.  The role is a binary OR
# of the different roles a user can have:
#
# - simple client such as a wallet: CLIENT
# - non-validating peer: PEER
# - validating client: VALIDATOR
# - auditing client: AUDITOR
#
eca:
        # This hierarchy is used to create the Pre-key tree, affiliations is the top of this hierarchy, 'banks_and_institutions' is used to create the key associated to auditors of both banks and
        # institutions, 'banks' is used to create a key associated to auditors of banks, 'bank_a' is used to create a key associated to auditors of bank_a, etc.
        affiliations:
           banks_and_institutions:
              banks:
                  - bank_a
                  - bank_b
                  - bank_c
              institutions:
                  - institution_a
        users:
                #
                # The fields of each user are as follows:
                #    <EnrollmentID>: <system_role (1:client, 2: peer, 4: validator, 8: auditor)> <EnrollmentPWD> <Affiliation> <Affiliation_Role> <JSON_Metadata>
                #
                # The optional JSON_Metadata field is of the following format:
                #   { "registrar": { "roles": <array-of-role-names>, "delegateRoles": <array-of-role-names> } }
                # The 'registrar' section is used to control access to registration of new users directly via the ECAA.RegisterUser GRPC call.
                # (See the 'fabric/membersrvc/protos/ca.proto' file for the definition of ECAA.RegisterUser.)
                # Note that this also controls who can register users via the client SDK.
                #
                # Only users with a 'registrar' section may be a registrar to register other users.  In particular,
                # 1) the "roles" field specifies which member roles may be registered by this user, and
                # 2) the "delegateRoles" field specifies which member roles may become the "roles" field of registered users.
                # The valid role names are "client", "peer", "validator", and "auditor".
                #
                # Example1:
                #    The 'admin' user below can register clients, peers, validators, or auditors; furthermore, the 'admin' user can register other
                #    users who can then register clients only.
                #
                # Example2:
                #    The 'WebAppAdmin' user below can register clients only, but none of the users registered by this user can register other users.
                #
                admin: 1 Xurw3yU9zI0l institution_a '{"registrar":{"roles":["client","peer","validator","auditor"],"delegateRoles":["client"]}}'
                WebAppAdmin: 1 DJY27pEnl16d institution_a '{"registrar":{"roles":["client"]}}'
                lukas: 1 NPKYL39uKbkj bank_a
                system_chaincode_invoker: 1 DRJ20pEql15a institution_a
                diego: 1 DRJ23pEQl16a institution_a
                jim: 1 6avZQLwcUe9b bank_a
                binhn: 1 7avZQLwcUe9q institution_a

                # Users for asset transfer with roles test located at
                # sdk/node/test/unit/asset-mgmt-with-roles.js
                alice: 1 CMS10pEQlB16 bank_a
                bob: 1 NOE63pEQbL25 bank_a
                assigner: 1 Tc43PeqBl11 bank_a

                vp: 4 f3489fy98ghf

                test_vp0: 4 MwYpmSRjupbT
                test_vp1: 4 5wgHK9qqYaPy
                test_vp2: 4 vQelbRvja7cJ
                test_vp3: 4 9LKqKH5peurL
                test_vp4: 4 Pqh90CEW5juZ
                test_vp5: 4 FfdvDkAdY81P
                test_vp6: 4 QiXJgHyV4t7A
                test_vp7: 4 twoKZouEyLyB
                test_vp8: 4 BxP7QNh778gI
                test_vp9: 4 wu3F1EwJWHvQ

# Uncomment this section to activate devnet setup as specficied in
# devnet-setup.md
#
#               vp0: 4 vp0_secret
#               vp1: 4 vp1_secret

                test_user0: 1 MS9qrN8hFjlE bank_a
                test_user1: 1 jGlNl6ImkuDo institution_a
                test_user2: 1 zMflqOKezFiA bank_c
                test_user3: 1 vWdLCE00vJy0 bank_a
                test_user4: 1 4nXSrfoYGFCP institution_a
                test_user5: 1 yg5DVhm0er1z bank_b
                test_user6: 1 b7pmSxzKNFiw bank_a
                test_user7: 1 YsWZD4qQmYxo institution_a
                test_user8: 1 W8G0usrU7jRk bank_a
                test_user9: 1 H80SiB5ODKKQ institution_a

                test_nvp0: 2 iywrPBDEPl0K bank_a
                test_nvp1: 2 DcYXuRSocuqd institution_a
                test_nvp2: 2 flpChShlY7xt bank_c
                test_nvp3: 2 jeruawMomclo bank_a
                test_nvp4: 2 RMYVxSZCk370 institution_a
                test_nvp5: 2 XHYVCIJGZGK7 bank_b
                test_nvp6: 2 4cIn63j8ahYp bank_a
                test_nvp7: 2 E7FAJUtWVn2h institution_a
                test_nvp8: 2 LJu8DkUilBEH bank_a
                test_nvp9: 2 VlEsBsiyXSjw institution_a
```

Comment: I would check this location first `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v0.6/membersrvc/membersrvc.yaml` If not there, I would try to use the `find` command on your file system.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the docker images so locally could not grep for that... I have seen that the file inside the docker is at /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/membersrvc/membersrvc.yaml and seems to be self explanatory in its comments.

Comment: Maybe what you see in `membersrvc.yaml` is just a hashed value of the password (_Xurw3yU9zI0l_) you are using for the admin user. Just guessing ..

Answer (score 4):

To add other users or change the admin password, you can create your own membersrvc.yml and use it when you start the membersrvc using docker.

You can edit the compose file to map your local membersrv.file, like:

```
membersrvc:
  # try 'docker ps' to see the container status after starting this compose
  container_name: membersrvc
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc
  expose:
    - "7054"
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  environment:
    - MEMBERSRVC_CA_ACA_ENABLED=true
    - MEMBERSRVC_CA_TCA_ATTRIBUTE-ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=true
  volumes:
    - /[path to your membersrvc.yml file]/membersrvc.yaml:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/membersrvc/membersrvc.yaml
```

Here is a documentation on the CA : http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Setup/ca-setup/

Comment: Thanks. That will help. I had seen the ca-setup page in readthedocs but it does not explain too much. The most info I have found is in the example membersrvc.yaml file in my docker image, where I found that format is: <EnrollmentID>: <system_role (1:client, 2: peer, 4: validator, 8: auditor)> <EnrollmentPWD> <Affiliation> <Affiliation_Role> <JSON_Metadata> Any link where it explains more in detail about these affiliations, roles, ... ? thanks.

Comment: I added the content of the example configuration... but for example, none of the examples has "Affiliation_Role" to see what that is for. Somebody corrects me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I didn't find any documentation on this either. You can maybe try to ask this on the hyperledger fabric chat : [https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-ca](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-ca). With luck you might have your answer

Comment: I've done exactly this but it keeps getting overwritten with the same default file. How to prevent that?

Comment: @s.matthew.english This works for me. I can see my custom file in /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/membersrvc/ of the membersrvc container. Did you try to login with your new user ?

Comment: yeah, you're right it worked- I was accidently logging into the wrong docker container and then just `cat`ing the file, when I logging to the membersvc docker I saw it worked- but anyway- thanks for following up!